# Get Date from week no, month, and day in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date variable:

```
temp_date = '2019-03-15'
```

I've calculated the `week no. of the month` and `day` using datetime:

I got **week_no = 3** and **day = 'Friday'**.

I want to find what date it was in February,January and december for the same week-day combination.

i.e:  date for February,Week3,Friday(Ans: 2019-02-15) &

date for January,Week3,Friday(Ans: 2019-01-18).

date for December,Week3,Friday(Ans: 2018-12-14)

I tried:

```
feb= (current_date + timedelta(weeks=4)).strftime ('%d-%m-%Y')
jan= (current_date + timedelta(weeks=8)).strftime ('%d-%m-%Y')
dec= (current_date + timedelta(weeks=12)).strftime ('%d-%m-%Y')
```

I got Jan and Feb dates correctly but for december i got (2018-12-21).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is this your actual code? You are adding the `timedelta` instead of subtracting it. If you are after December 2019, you should add 40 weeks instead of subtracting 12.

Comment: Your premise is wrong if you're expecting `2018-12-14` to pop up. If you want the *third Friday of the month*, then December 21 is that. December 14 is the second, December 7 is the first, and November 30 was the Friday before that.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Did you mean November 30?

Comment: @Selcuk ~You fool, everyone knows November doesn't exist!~ *fixed

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I thought it was Australia that didn't exist but I may be wrong.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while, using `isoweek` along with `monthrange` from `calendar` should do it:

```
from isoweek import Week
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

year = 2019
weekDay = 3
jan_date = Week(year, weekDay).friday()

Feb = monthrange(year, 2)[1]   # 28 Days for 2nd month
Mar = monthrange(year, 3)[1]   # 31 Days for 3rd month
Apr = monthrange(year, 4)[1]   # 30 Days for 4th month

feb_date = jan_date + datetime.timedelta(days=Feb)
mar_date = feb_date + datetime.timedelta(days=Mar)
apr_date = mar_date + datetime.timedelta(days=Apr)

print(feb_date)   # Feb 28 Days
print(mar_date)   # Mar 31 Days
print(apr_date)   # Apr 30 Days
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2019-02-15
2019-03-18
2019-04-17
```

> Note: This is being done iteratively, adding the number of months from
>   previous ones.